# MacBook Pro Retina 13" Late 2012 SSD Upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade

I've done some research before, which led to the installation of an SD card adapter, together with a 128GB microSD card, which doubles the available storage capacity (original SSD storage was 128GB). Unfortunately that's far from enough and I am considering a further upgrade.

I've again done some research and found [this](https://www.amazon.de/Transcend-JetDrive-interne-MacBook-Retina/dp/B00JKCHMMS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1413217641&tag=dde0b6-21), which is unfortunately almost double the price of ordinary mSATA or m.2 SSDs, which are readily available on the internet these days.

Therefore I am looking for alternatives, as I am not willing to pay this ridiculous premium for Apple-compatible hardware.

Now I've also found [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153414/macbook-pro-retina-13-late-2012-ssd-replacement-putting-in-a-sata-2-5-ssd-dr), which mentions the possibility of the installment of an ordinary 2.5" SATA SSD into the laptop.
This seems to be possible, at least if [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2012+SSD+Tray+Replacement/12822) is any kind of authority.

Unfortunately in the original thread no one seems to have been able to find the right adapter. Has this become possible in the meantime, alas, has anyone found the right adapter to actually achieve this feat?

The last option I found, maybe the most promising one is something like [this](https://www.amazon.de/Adapter-Macbook-Retina-M-ware%C2%AE-ID14828/dp/B00NOHLHYY), an adapter from Apple's proprietary socket to m.2 or similarly to [mSATA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OQG630U).

Now my question basically is: Has anyone made any kind of experiences with any of the aforementioned ideas and if so, how have they fared? What would you recommend, the adapter, the 2.5" hack, or the overpriced transcend version?

Comment: Has noone ever made any kind of experience with a m.2 adapter ssd upgrade with this macpro model?